# PHP replacement for MySQL Now()

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I do a lots of queries like:

```
SELECT THIS
FROM THAT
WHERE ROW_TIME < NOW()
```

How to create variable in PHP that will contain current time so i can make this work:

```
SELECT THIS
FROM THAT
WHERE ROW_TIME < '$variable'
```

?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575601/datetime-now-php-mysql-pdo-variant

Comment: @6747467454 not Duplicate

Comment: "Tim S" gave you the answer, but still using the mysql function NOW() will be faster, than using the PHP date() function. Why exactly do you need to create a variable in PHP ?

Comment: To be it faster. I have a case when i need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the PHP [`date($format)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns current time as a string. You can set the format using a string.

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: will it be safe for time zones?

Comment: Why do you need time zones, when this gives you the server time. NOW() also gives you the server's time.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function will help.

Comment: Really? I had no idea. You knew what I meant so your comment is pointless.

Comment: I dont understand you. Sorry date is for time also, but its so broad answer it does not help me

Comment: I was directing you to the function that will help you. Spend a little time on that page and you'd find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use time() - it returns a timestamp. http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: time() doesn't return the same as mysql's NOW()