# How Insert now() function in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do an update in MySQL from PHP with CodeIgniter, but, how can I insert a `now()` method?
I mean, I'm using an array to insert my information, but, how can I insert the date?
This is an example of my array:

```
$data = array(
   'name'     => $inputName,
   'lastname' => $inputLast,
   'DOBirth'  => now()
);
```

Comment: you need to put here NOW() and your query must be made something like this:-$insert = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (column mane comma seperated ) VALUES (?, NOW())");

Comment: I had to specify that, I'm using MVC to do my app

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is part of MySQL, not PHP, so you need to put into the query.

Try this way, which is how you handle it using PDO.  This should work:

```
$stmt = $pdoDb->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename (name, lastname, dobirth) VALUES (:name, :lastname, NOW())');
// either bind each parameter explicitly 
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->execute();
```

source: [Datetime NOW PHP mysql (+ PDO variant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575601/datetime-now-php-mysql-pdo-variant)

Comment: OP is using CodeIgniter Active Record.